# Learning C# and trying to work around error

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I want to be able to use the MS speech SDK to transcribe speech to text. I got this sample from the Microsoft documentation  but it gives me the error "program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point" when I try to build the solution.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make it work?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace SpeechToText
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("5626c4797ab3c6d061b8", "Werope");

            var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            // Creates a speech recognizer using file as audio input.
            // Replace with your own audio file name.
            using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"whatstheweatherlike.wav"))
            {
                using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
                {
                    // Subscribes to events.
                    recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                    };

                    recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                        }
                        else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                        }
                    };

                    recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

                        if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                        }

                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    };

                    recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
                    };

                    recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                        Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    };

                    // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
                    await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Waits for completion.
                    // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
                    Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

                    // Stops recognition.
                    await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @lloyd that depends on the c# version your'e using. You can have an async main in c# 7.1

Comment: @canton7 Realized my mistake when I searched it up.

Comment: Adding `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>` to `<PropertyGroup>` in your `.csproj` file should do the trick.

Comment: Lang version worked , thank you